# Convert Image Into Cells

Tags: matlab

How can I convert an image into cells? I am getting an error while running this one in the conversion of mat2cell:

```
close all;
I=imread('D:\prj2.jpg');
Imshow(I);
C=mat2cell(I,[130 97],[130 97]);
```

Comment: What error are you getting? What is the size of I? (run `size(I)` to find out)

Comment: ??? Error using ==> mat2cell at 96
Number of input vector arguments, 2, does not match the input matrix's number of dimensions, 3.

Error in ==> prj at 4
C=mat2cell(I,[130 97],[130 97]);

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for `mat2cell`:

```
 mat2cell Break matrix up into a cell array of matrices.
    C = mat2cell(X,M,N) breaks up the 2-D array X into a cell array...
```

This is how you are currently using the function mat2cell. However, from your error message it appears that your matrix `I` is not a 2D matrix. If you type `ndims(I)` into the command line, you can see how many dimensions your array has.

From your error message, you can see that your `I` has 3 dimensions ( the third dimension of the image is for each colour channel). You must therefore use `mat2cell` differently. Type `help mat2cell` into the command prompt, and read about using `mat2cell` for multidimensional arrays.

Alternatively, you could extract each colour channel separately from your image first, and run `mat2cell` on each colour channel separately:

```
red_channel = I(:, :, 1);
green_channel = I(:, :, 2);
blue_channel = I(:, :, 3);
```

Comment: how to convert rgb to frames  M(1)=im2frame(red_channel,map);
M(2)=im2frame(green_channel,map);
M(3)=im2frame(blue_channel,map);
??? Undefined function or variable 'map'.

Error in ==> prj at 7
M(1)=im2frame(red_channel,map);

Comment: hi any one can help me in writting matlab code  for converting image into frames and then applying turbulence simulation and then converting frames into video.

Comment: Great comments. Maybe these would be best as separate questions, it is very hard to answer them here.